# IS There any condition for not deleting the images in Word ,via C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, shapes, blueprism

I have a code in C# ,for deleting Blank Pages (even those pages that may have spaces on it) And it works correctly for those cases,,, but ,My weird problem is that if the page has an image it deletes it,While if the page has a combination of image and text ,it do not delete it.

Can someone explain me ,where might be my problem?

Below is my code

```cs
String wordPath = @Path; 

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordapp = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs paragraphs = null;

try
{
    // Start Word APllication and set it be invisible

    wordapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    wordapp.Visible = false;

    doc = wordapp.Documents.Open(wordPath);
    paragraphs = doc.Paragraphs;

    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
  
    WdStatistic stat1 = WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
    int numberOfPages = doc.ComputeStatistics(stat1, ref miss);

    var document1 = wordapp.ActiveDocument;

    for (int i = 1; i < numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);

        document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, i, miss);

        Console.WriteLine("-> TEXT : " + document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark, miss, miss, "\\page").Text);
        Console.WriteLine("-> longitud : " + document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text.Trim().Length);

        if (document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text.Trim().Length <= 1)
        {
            document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Delete();
        }

        if (document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text.Trim().Length <= 1 || document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text.Trim() == "\f")
        {
            foreach (Paragraph paragraph in document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paragraphs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     PARAGRAPH!" + paragraph.Range.Text + "!");

                if (paragraph.Range.Text.Trim() == string.Empty || document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text.Trim() == "\f")
                {
                    paragraph.Range.Select();
                    wordapp.Selection.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    // Save the document and close document
    doc.Save();

    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)doc).Close();

    // Quit the word application
    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)wordapp).Quit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    // Clean up the unmanaged Word COM resources by explicitly
    // call Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject on all accessor objects

    if (paragraphs != null)
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(paragraphs);
        paragraphs = null;
    }

    if (doc != null)
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
        doc = null;
    }

    if (wordapp != null)
    {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordapp);
        wordapp = null;
    }
}
// end
```

Comment: What type of image? InlineShape or Shape? Note that inline shapes are represented in text as a character and you delete when text.length <= 1 so you will delete a page with only 1 picture. Tip, in the debugger check what is in the Selection object, eg. Selection.InlineShapes.count and Selection.ShapeRange.count (latter for shapes)

Comment: @Boeryepes honestly I have startlearning C# these 2 last months and Can make the difference of InlineShape or Shape ,,but the image is like a "Screenshot".

about the part that you said you delete a page with one picture ,it is TRUE.
THE PAGES THAT ARE DELETED WITH IMAGES HAS ONLY ONE IMAGE.

Answer (score 1):

You're just looking for Text:

`document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text.Trim().Length <= 1`

I think you also need to look for 'InlineShapes' which would include things like images and drawings:

`document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes.Count == 0`

So probably something like

```
    if (document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Text.Trim().Length <= 1
        && document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.InlineShapes.Count == 0)
    {
        document1.ActiveWindow.Selection.Delete();
    }
```

... although I don't really understand what your second 'if' block is for,  you probably need something similar there too

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple.
If you have 1 picture without text and the picture is an inlineShape (picture that moves with text), then text.lenght = 1 so the <= 1 check will succeeed and the picture is deleted

If you don't want it to be deleted then simply check on (VB.NET):

```
Selection.Text.trim.length = 0 AndAlso Selection.range.shaperange.count = 0
```

Notes:

- shaperange holds the pictures that do not move with text
- note that selection.shaperange.count returns 0 even if a shape is selected
- selection.range.shaperange.count does return a non-0 when a shape is selected
- to detect empty tables extra logic needs to be added

The debugger is your friend whenever the results are weird. Inspect the Selection object diligently.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242680/discussion-on-answer-by-boeryepes-is-there-any-condition-for-not-deleting-the-im).

Comment: the code deletes me the floating images
What should I change ?

Comment: You should read the comments that are posted. The answer is in my first comment. I understand that you are new to this but you cannot continue coming back asking "help what do i need to do?" every time something unexpectedly happens. At least show that you make an effort to solve it yourself

Comment: @Boeryepes i have tried it will all the ways that I know,But still it didtn catch the floating images.